# Smallest number of rectangles covering marked parts of grid

Tags: algorithms

I have an N by N grid of cells, and certain blocks are marked:

```
+--+---+---+---+
|  |   |   |   |
|  | x | x |   |
|  | x | x |   |
|  |   |   |   |
|  |   |   | x |
+--+---+---+---+
```

I would like to find a set of non-overlapping rectangles that covers all marks but not the unmarked cells. In the example that would be 2, one with topleft corner at (2,2) of size 2x2 and on of size 1x1 at (5,4)

Does anyone know an algorithm or the formal name of this problem?

Comment: One rectangle always suffices. Do the requirements also say that you should prefer smaller rectangles? If so, should you optimize for the number or for the minimal maximal area, or for the number of "wasted" squares within the rectangles, or for something else?

Comment: ["Covering" is the right word.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygon_covering) However, pay attention to the related terms (e.g. minimum vs minimal) as mentioned in the Wikipedia articles, as these terms may be used to differentiate algorithms with different optimizations. Another search term relevant to your case is "rectilinear polygon". Good luck.

Comment: @KilianFoth My specification was insufficient, as a rectangle covering the whole grid would always be a trivial optimal solution. I'm looking to cover *only* the marked cells :)

Comment: I'd suggest digging into the automated [Karnaugh map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map) solvers as they deal with a variant of this problem (the 'world' is not a rectangle itself, but rather a torus).

Comment: @MichaelT Thanks for the suggestion. I had thought of that but I don't think they will be useful as Karnaugh maps assume overlap is allowed.

Comment: I think this might be equivalent to the bin packing problem. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem

Comment: So for a grid with 2,2 2,3 3,2 3,3 3,4 4,3 4,4 you need three rectangles because of the non overlapping rule?